# How can I synchronize effectively a large directory containing lots of photos between 3 LAN / different OS hosts?

Tags: rsync, synchronization, dropbox

This would be working between Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, Windows 7 and Windows XP?

I would like to achieve something like Dropbox service, but only in local network.

What I currently use:
Ubuntu has the Samba server installed and I am syncing the Windows boxes via SyncToy.

Problems I have with it are:

- How to keep all the 3 copies in sync? (without differences between hosts(!))
- Manually syncing is not really convenient, it should be "half-automatic"
- Dependency issues between 3 copies: Delete files on host #1, change the same file on #2, and manually sync the #3 :/

As far as I know, best option would be to use the one "central file storage" and make backups of it,
remaining two hosts should mount the directory remotely.

What I looked into so far:
- rsync (Unison? - not sure on how to properly use it)
- Dropbox (great but req. network connection all the time -> cloud, limited storage space!)

How to solve it better? Please note that this should work between Linux and 2 Windows versions.

Thanks, Andrzej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run rsync on windows, via cygwin (and possibly other ways as well)

also http://fak3r.com/geek/howto-build-your-own-open-source-dropbox-clone/
I've not had a chance to play with it yet, but I do plan on setting it up.